# Negative time in Excel that isn't supposed to be negative

Tags: excel, datetime, time

I'm trying to subtract 2 timepoints which excel is registering as negative when it shouldn't be. Time 1= 00:40 and Time 2=00:20 . Time 1- Time 2 should equal 00:20 but Excel seems to think this is a negative number. The formula I have is a bit more complex as it involves a Look Up function and I only have this problem on 2 of the lookup values (Other values are 00:45 and 01:00). Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the underlying values are actually datetimes and you are attempting to subtract tomorrow at 00:20 from today at 00:40 (-23:40). If so, peel off the time value from the datetime with the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) as in `MOD(A1, 1)-MOD(A2, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted one of the lookup values and it's registering the correct time now. Might be because one of the words in the lookup vector/value repeated itself (e.g. a in one cell and a b in a cell further down). I'm guessing Excel got confused? Although both result vectors in this case had the same time (00:20) so don't know what's going on there!

Comment: Welcome to Excel time values and the [15 digit precision floating point errors](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). It is very possible that one of the values was different by a very small amount.

Comment: Yes, when using lookups with number values as an index I usually round to the minute to prevent missing an item due to nMilliseconds difference.

Comment: I still don't understand why it would be negative though. Why is 00:40-00:20 negative when using the lookup function even when accounting for negligible numbers?